# Parameters in form action url disappear?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form action="create_page.php?subject=<?php echo urlencode($current_subject["id"]); ?>" method="post">
```

After the form been submitted, the `$current_subject["id"]` vanishes.
I know it happens in **GET** method, but why would it disappear in POST method?

Strange things happen when the form does not pass my validation function, the parameter stays there. But when it passes, it goes away. I know I could use hidden field, but I am curious why this happens.

Comment: what is `$current_subject["id"]` and do you have a value set in create_page.php for the same?

Comment: It is a value that I want to append it to the url so that I could do some validation before sending it to mysql.

Comment: it is a single-validation page by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be seems you have an empty value for `$current_subject["id"]` so try to a check

```
if(!empty($current_subject["id"])) {
  // do yourstuff
}
```

or for best alternate way try to use as a hidden in form

```
 <form action="create_page.php">
    <input type ="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php echo urlencode($current_subject['id']);?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will not work and for that you need to go back to the definition of GET and POST.

In GET request the form parameters are encoded in the URL and is called a query string.
So using

`$_GET` will expect the parameters in the query string.

A POST request passes the form parameters in the body of the HTTP request, not in the URL.

So using `$_POST` will expect the data in the HTTP request not in the query string.

And this is the very reason why data is passed in the hidden field as in your example.

Comment: But the $current_subject["id"] is not in the body(it is not something user enters), it was in the url part. So I cant send it to the action url to make it append to the url again?

Comment: You can append query string to the request URL but remember in the receiving end you can not catch the value using $_POST. You can check how data is sent using some browser developer tools, that will give you more information.